# how to start B class at every specific time on android?

Tags: android

I want use `String start = "16:00";` in specific time, start another activity.

I must use `String start = "16:00"`

MainActivity.class

```
String start = "16:00";

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAlarmTime(this);
}

private void setAlarmTime(Context context) {
      String[] strStart = start.split(":") // delete ":"

      Calendar cal_start = Calendar.getInstance();

      cal_start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strStart[0])); // hour
      cal_start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strStart[1])); //minute

      AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
      alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal_start.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
}
```

I want while the app is running, current time 4 o'clock , start `AlarmActivity.class` .

But it does not work.

How to  every specific time start another activity on android?

@update

```
 private void setAlarmTime(Context context) {

    String[] strStart = start.split(":");

    Calendar cal_start = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal_start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strStart[0]));
    cal_start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strStart[1]));

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_start.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

this source not work.
not work alarmManager.

Comment: you want to trigger that activity on 4'o clock. right?

Comment: @curiousMind  yes but I must use `String start = "16:00";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this permission in your manifest

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

register your receiver class in the application tag in the manifest file

```
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmActivity" />
```

Resister your alarm that will trigger AlarmActivity at a specific time in your case its 16:00

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Make sure your register class extend BroadcastReceiver like this

```
        class AlarmActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                  // Do whatever you want 
                  // you can generate notifications here 
                  // or can start your application activity you want 
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider to use AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP if you need to wake up the device even if it goes off.

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_start.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

AlarmManager.RTC will NOT wake the device up.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC

Btw, you do not need to pass the context reference to method:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this /*can use this as it is a context already */ , 0, intent, 0);
```

Update:
Please also set the second and millisecond of the cal_start; otherwise it will be the values that you get the calendar instance.

```
cal_start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal_start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Update 2:
It works in my side, you may try to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

in Manifests.

Btw, if you want this alarm repeat every day

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_start.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Comment: thanks, but not work. please check update my question

Comment: ha.. this not work.. perhaps use AlarmManager need permission?